# WPF Binding children property of a custom control to parent

Tags: wpf, binding, custom-controls

I'm new to WPF. I'm trying to create a custom control with a HorizontalContentAlignment property that will change according to the setting of the container.

```
<Style x:Key="SimpleRadioButton" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20 10 20 0"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
</Style>
```

And then set them in the parent container.

```
<ctrl:ToggleExpander
    Header="Worklist"
    IsChecked="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
    IsToggleEnabled="True">
    <StackPanel>
        <ctrl:SideBarPanel
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
            Header="map provider">
            <RadioButton
                Content="Finished"
                IsChecked="True"
                Style="{DynamicResource SimpleRadioButton}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ctrl:ToggleExpander>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to go about it? Thanks! And sorry for my English.

Comment: `RelativeSource TemplatedParent` is intended to be used in a ControlTemplate. Try `RelativeSource AncestorType=ctrl:SideBarPanel` instead. And of course add a source property path, i.e. `Path=HorizontalContentAlignment`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is the container might not be SideBarPanel. I want it can be used in any type of container, not just SideBarPanel. I don't know if WPF allows it or not.

Comment: You could simply bind the RadioButton's HorizontalContentAlignment property directly, instead of doing that in a Style.

Comment: Is your plan to set this property and then it's value is applied to all children? And. Will the ui within the panel or whatever be fairly flat?

Comment: @Andy Yes, I want the parent set the value and it will be applied to all children. And the UI can be whatever, not just the panel.

Comment: @Clemens I can do that, but if the parent contains a lot of children elements then it quite cumbersome to do the binding to all the children. I want to look for something that can apply to all children.

Comment: You could have a dependency property marketd as inherits and an onchange handler. That'll fire for all child controls. Set the value on them in the handler.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the following, and your radiobutton will take the value of the first parent framework element (for example in this case your ctrl:SideBarPanel)

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType=FrameworkElement}, Path=HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks man. But this one doesn't work. It said that there's no Path property in RelativeSource type.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this symply way in xaml:

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Binding Path="HorizontalAlignment" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorLevel=1,AncestorType=FrameworkElement}" />
        </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I hope help you